# Is it possible to go behind those walls?

Tags: trackmania-forever

I added some walls on the following track: is it possible to go behind those walls (e.g. by climbing or somehow going through it)?

[image]

[image]

I use these walls:

[image]

with these road blocks:

[image]

You can download the track [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lzee6s97ekoyzqy/crossover2.Challenge.Gbx?dl=0).

Comment: I'm still interested in the answer.

Comment: If anyone has any idea.